# QLineEdit returns empty string

Tags: python, pyqt, menubar, qlineedit

I'm trying to access the text written in a QLineEdit from another class, but it is returning an empty string.

Here is a minimalistic functional piece of code (Python 2.7):

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.createmenus()
        self.initui()

        self.central_widget = QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        testWidgets = Container0()
        self.central_widget.addWidget(testWidgets)

    def initui(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("TestWindow")
        self.show()

    def createmenus(self):
        viewFile = self.menuBar().addMenu("File")

        expMenu = QMenu("Export", self)
        expAct = QAction("Save", self)
        expMenu.addAction(expAct)

        expMenu.triggered[QAction].connect(self.export_config)

        viewFile.addMenu(expMenu)

    def export_config(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save as", "C:/", "Text (*.txt);;All Files (*)",
                                              options=options)
        if fileName:
            Export().export(fileName)

class Container0(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__()

        self.mainlayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.vbox_layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.text1 = QLineEdit()
        print self.text1

        self.vbox_layout.addWidget(self.text1)
        self.mainlayout.addLayout(self.vbox_layout)

class Export():
    def export(self, path):
        tw = Container0()

        t1 = tw.text1
        t1text = t1.text()

        print t1
        print t1text
        print path

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**About the code:**

First of all I create my `QMainWindow`, which calls the functions `initui` and `createmenus`. In the next class `Container0` I implement the `QLineEdit` widget. I separated the classes because the application I'm writing has several windows and a toolbar with "next" and "back" buttons, which change the `centralWidget` to the class I saved the window I want to display next. (I hope this wasnt't a bad idea)

**What I want to achieve**

Currently when I write something into the `QLineEdit` and then go to the Menu "File -> Export -> Save" and insert a path, the code calls the class `Export` and its function `export`, which should read the string I wrote in the `QLineEdit` and print it among the path. The problem is that my output from my QLineEdit is an empty string. Furthermore, the function `Export` seems to create another instance from the `QLineEdit`. Note the different memory locations when I call `print self.text1`:

```
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QLineEdit object at 0x0000000002968B88>
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QLineEdit object at 0x0000000002968DC8>
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QLineEdit object at 0x0000000002968DC8>
                                                        ### <- This is the empty line
C:/123
```

This makes me wonder how I can call the `QLineEdit` string without creating another instance. Furthermore, is this a correct way to handle multiple windows?

**TL,DR:** `QLineEdit` returns an empty string. It should not. Suggestions about the code structure are also welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you use the following expression:

```
some_variable = Container0()
```

you are creating a new container, so in your case the container created in the `__init__` of `MainWindow` is different from the one created in the `export` method of `Export`. Therefore, even if you place text in the main window, there is no text in the other Container.

The solution is to make `testWidgets` member of the class and pass the text content to export:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.createmenus()
        self.initui()

        self.central_widget = QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        self.testWidgets = Container0()
        self.central_widget.addWidget(self.testWidgets)

    def initui(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("TestWindow")
        self.show()

    def createmenus(self):
        viewFile = self.menuBar().addMenu("File")

        expMenu = QMenu("Export", self)
        expAct = QAction("Save", self)
        expMenu.addAction(expAct)

        expMenu.triggered[QAction].connect(self.export_config)

        viewFile.addMenu(expMenu)

    def export_config(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save as", "C:/", "Text (*.txt);;All Files (*)",
                                              options=options)
        if fileName:
            Export().export(fileName, self.testWidgets.text1.text())

class Container0(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__()

        self.mainlayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.vbox_layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.text1 = QLineEdit()
        print(self.text1)

        self.vbox_layout.addWidget(self.text1)
        self.mainlayout.addLayout(self.vbox_layout)

class Export():
    def export(self, path, t1text):
        print(t1text)
        print(path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Oh Christ, I feel so dumb now. Thanks a lot for your help! On a side note, how would you do it if you had not one `QLineEdit`, but like 20 of them? Would you pass them individually to the function `export`, with a list or dictionary? Or would you change the structure entirely?

Comment: @Iridium What you would do is a list or dictionary of them, as appropriate, and then create a method that iterates, concatenates and returns the data.